VMware Workstation repair installation is not working
When I try to repair my VMware Workstation installation, I get an error saying that I must have administrative privileges to repair the software. I have tried running the Control Panel as an administrator and attempting the repair again, but I still get the same result.
I need a fix as soon as possible because I have virtual machines for my studies that I don't want to lose.
I am using VMware Workstation version 17.5.2 on Windows 11.
Thanks in advance!
error:


Try running the installer directly.
